# Why is a collection created outside of the main.js file in the server folder?

Tags: meteor, collections

From what I believe, the mongo collections should be stored in the backend and should give data to the front end upon request.  In the documentation(https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections) it says to create a imports folder (which I already have) and to call it there. Why is the collection created outside of the server folder?  I've created a meteor app before and it turned out to be really slow when first loading the page, but is fast when visiting others.  I think this was from calling the entire collection in the imports folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you understand the difference between the collection object and the data.

The former is just a container. In Meteor you use the same code in both Server and Client, but it actually behaves slightly differently: on Server the collection accesses your full Mongo database, whereas on Client it accesses only your client side Minimongo.

Then the data is copied from server to client minimongo through publication and subscription. As long as you keep the `autopublish` package for prototyping, it publishes and subscribes your entire data for you, so you do not have to manage the pub/sub, and you may think that all the data is always entirely copied in the client. This also makes your initial page loading long, since you transfer all the data.

Therefore it sounds like you just reach the time when you should now stop using the `autopublish` package and start managing pub/sub.